# Как написать SQL в Access запрос на выведение данных по текущей дате

Tags: access

У меня есть Таблица Временный_пропуски_Водителей в ней есть поле Время отбытия, тип данных: Дата и время. Мне нужно сделать SQL запрос который будет выводить, кто находится в данный момент на территории по времени то есть, если текущая дата и время будут меньше чем дата и время в поле "Время отбытия" то данные выведутся, если нет то не выведутся, но мне нужно сделать ограничение, что бы поля у которых дата будет следующий день, не выводились.
Вот как я это сделал:

```
SELECT * FROM Временные_пропуски_Водители WHERE Now() < Время_отбытия  AND Время_отбытия > Now();
```

Но данный SQL запрос всё равно выводит как текущую дату так и будущую.

Comment: Написан я такой вот код и он вроде работает корректно
SELECT *
FROM Временные_пропуски_Водители
WHERE IIf(IsNull([Время_отбытия]), False, (DateValue([Время_отбытия]) = Date() AND CDate([Время_отбытия]) > Now()));
Но в VS WindiwsForm когда я пытаюсь создать TableAdapter он пишет что
Ошибка в списке аргументов функции: "=" не распознан.
Ошибка в списке аргументов функции: "AND" не распознан.
Не удается выполнить синтаксический разбор текста запроса.